# Changing the screen orientation while waiting for question preview crashes the Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, markdown-preview

How to reproduce:

1. Tap *Ask Question* (the Q icon)
2. Press *Preview* button, a loading indicator will appear.
3. Before it completes, change the orientation.
4. The loading indicator goes away, and the app crashes.

LogCat

```
03-03 14:59:38.442: E/AndroidRuntime(16869): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-03 14:59:38.442: E/AndroidRuntime(16869): Process: com.stackexchange.marvin, PID: 16869
03-03 14:59:38.442: E/AndroidRuntime(16869): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{15c9a58 V.E...... R......D 0,0-1026,348} not attached to window manager
03-03 14:59:38.442: E/AndroidRuntime(16869):    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:424)
03-03 14:59:38.442: E/AndroidRuntime(16869):    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:350)
03-03 14:59:38.442: E/AndroidRuntime(16869):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:116)
03-03 14:59:38.442: E/AndroidRuntime(16869):    at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:362)
03-03 14:59:38.442: E/AndroidRuntime(16869):    at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:345)
03-03 14:59:38.442: E/AndroidRuntime(16869):    at com.stackexchange.marvin.core.OperationThatCanFail$1.onPostExecute(OperationThatCanFail.java:87)
03-03 14:59:38.442: E/AndroidRuntime(16869):    at com.stackexchange.marvin.core.OperationThatCanFail$1.onPostExecute(OperationThatCanFail.java:68)
03-03 14:59:38.442: E/AndroidRuntime(16869):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
03-03 14:59:38.442: E/AndroidRuntime(16869):    at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
03-03 14:59:38.442: E/AndroidRuntime(16869):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
03-03 14:59:38.442: E/AndroidRuntime(16869):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-03 14:59:38.442: E/AndroidRuntime(16869):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
03-03 14:59:38.442: E/AndroidRuntime(16869):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
03-03 14:59:38.442: E/AndroidRuntime(16869):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-03 14:59:38.442: E/AndroidRuntime(16869):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
03-03 14:59:38.442: E/AndroidRuntime(16869):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Still repro'd on v1.0.83. A common error of not retaining the reference of the loading indicator view while changing the screen orientation.